# How to pass dynamic tablename to execute sql from rest api call

Tags: apache-nifi

I Have a requirement where i want to fetch data from mutiple database. The tablename whose data ​needs to be fetched the tablename whose data needs to be fetched are selected by the user and passed via UI. Through rest api i can pass the tableName but how to make executeSql call for each table seperatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, it may be a bit complicateda and daunting task. Nevertheless, the following explains how the value can be set.

`ExecuteSQL` which is a processor in NiFi can be configured using a `PUT` request with the endpoint `/processors/{id}` where `id` is the component's Id. And the basic payload for the PUT call should look something like:

```
{
    "revision": {
        "clientId": "ClientId",
        "version": 8,
        "lastModifier": "value"
    },
    "id": "12512325-0164-1000-530c-7474a72c24ca",
    "component": {
        "id": "12512325-0164-1000-530c-7474a72c24ca",
        "config": {
            "properties" : {
                "name-of-the-property": "YOUR_VALUE"
            }
        },
        "state": "RUNNING"
    }
}
```

The above JSON is only a part of the whole lot of DTOs supported by the `ProcessorEntity`. Among them, the following are the key things to lookout for:

1. **revision** - You have to keep track of the version somehow. Each change to a component increments the version number by 1. (Regardless of how the change was done i.e. UI or API)
2. **id** - Id of the component. In this case your instance of `ExecuteSQL` processor
3. **component.config.properties** - Key-Value pair of the Properties' name and the value that has to be set. Note: NiFi components' property has two names: `name` and `displayName`. you have to provide the name in the request.

You may want to do a `GET` request to get the information of the processor which would give you details about the component including the `revision` details and the `properties` details. You can parse through them and use it.

More details and handy guides on NiFi REST API:

- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html
- https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/87217/change-nifi-flow-using-rest-api-part-1.html